# Following a text or log file in Windows. Notepad++ perhaps?

Tags: windows, logging, text, notepad++, text-editor

I have a log file that keeps changing every couple of seconds. I'm using Windows 7 and would like to follow it. In Linux it would have been simple, just type `tailf log.log` in a shell. But how do I do this in Windows? Can anyone recommend any programs? Does notepad++ have an option for this sort of thing perhaps?

Comment: Sorry! I didn't know that this was apparently off-topic. Probably should have asked it in superuser. Anyway, on superuser [here](http://superuser.com/questions/68703/windows-xp-equivalent-of-tail-f) I also found out that you can use Powershell with `Get-Content <filename> -wait`, which is handy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notepad++ can do auto update of files. You can find the setting in `Settings -> Preferences... -> MISC -> File Status Auto-Detection`. Check all three boxes and the files will be updated on change and scrolled to the bottom. Only problem with this is that the Notepad++ window has to be in focus for it to update.

There is also a `Document Monitor plugin` for Notepad++ but I have never tried it myself.

Comment: Thank you ellak! That's really helpful. There is a way to do it in Powershell as I found out, but I prefer to keep everything in Notepad++. Thanks again!

Comment: `File -> Reload from Disk` also works. Map it to F5 in `Settings -> Shortcut Mapper`.